# Export to Excel

Tags: apex, visualforce, salesforceexcelconnector

I have VF page V1 with multiple page block table. I have a requirement to create a link to export one of the pageblocktable to excel. so decided to create  separate VF page to render the page block table in excel and point it from master VF.

I am populating excel sheet with just header and no values inside, because id field value is not passed on to the new page, my controller class uses id to SOQL.

VF1:

```
<apex:outputlink target="_self" value="/apex/Rep" >
  <apex:outputText value="Export To Excel" />
</apex:outputlink>
```

VF2:

```
    <apex:pageBlock id="rsbfpageBlock">


    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Rep}" var="a" rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(Rep))}" rows="{!rsbfpageSize}">

     <apex:column value="{!a.Field1}">
     <apex:facet name="header">   
       <apex:commandLink action="{!rsbfViewData}" value="Field1{!a.Field1}" id="cmdSort" reRender="rsbfpageBlock">
         <apex:param value="Field1" name="column" assignTo="{!rsbfsortExpression}" ></apex:param>
       </apex:commandLink>
     </apex:facet>
   </apex:column>

     <apex:column value="{!a.Field2}">
     <apex:facet name="header">   
       <apex:commandLink action="{!rsbfViewData}" value="Description{!a.Field2}" reRender="rsbfpageBlock">
         <apex:param value="Field2" name="column" assignTo="{!rsbfsortExpression}" ></apex:param>
       </apex:commandLink>
     </apex:facet>
   </apex:column>       

    </apex:form>
```

Could anyone of you help me in fixing the problem?

Comment: VF1: Code from calling page         <apex:outputlink target="_blank" value="/apex/RepSalesByFund" >
          <apex:outputText value="Export To Excel" />
        </apex:outputlink>

Comment: Did you set the second page to renderAs Excel?

Comment: Can you please post your the code for controller part also?